# Webbrowsercontrol not loading URL in custom task pane - Word Plugin

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, webbrowser-control

I am trying to load a web-application URL in a word plugin custom task pane(VSTO) inside a WPF webbrowsercontrol. The problem is that it is working fine on development machine and some other machines but it do not work on some machines. Below is my machine specific finding(All Machines have IE11):
[image]

I have tried using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/webview ,&&, https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/#34jyIaiQaMTrX2zR.97

As per findings on some threads, i enabled window.error on web page and removed some errors that were coming in javascript script. But on some machines it gives unspecified errors in jquery files. 
I have also tried setting browser emulation from registry for WINWORD.EXE to use IE11.

P.S. I have developed the vsto plugin on target framework 4.6. I have also tried using target framework 4.6.2 that is required for WEBVIEW control as mentioned in earlier links. Also, enabling .net version 4.7 on windows 10 machine do not work. Web page takes 3-4 seconds to load in IE.
The web page uses jquery1.9 and angular framework 1.6. And the page also contains meta tag for IE=edge as suggested on some sites.

Is there any other work around to make this work?

> > Some suggestion are about recreating the view in WPF, i can't create the web page in WPF to display and edit all the data due to strict delivery timelines.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the workaround described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/4490421/webbrowser-or-wpf-control-content-may-not-display-d-in-office

## Symptoms

In some situations, the WebBrowser or WPF control content may not display or function correctly in an Office application when the control is hosted inside a CustomTaskPane control.

## Cause

This issue might be caused by the WebBrowser or WPF controls themselves. Host applications that don't return focus to HTML elements which are rendered inside WebBrowser or WPF controls might also cause this issue.

## Workaround

To work around this issue, add an intermediary form between the CustomTaskPane control and the WebBrowser or WPF control. For more information about how to add a custom task pane to an application, see Add a custom task pane to an application.

For WPF control rendering issues, we recommend that you host a WPF UserControl inside a WindowsForm and add an intermediary form. To add an intermediary form, see Walkthrough: Hosting a 3-D WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms.

For WebBrowser control rendering issues, use the UserControl MyUserControl to implement the workaround as follows:

```
// ThisAddIn.cs

namespace TaskPaneWorkaround
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private MyUserControl myUserControl1;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            myUserControl1 = new MyUserControl();
            myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "My Task Pane");
            myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

// MyUserControl.cs

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TaskPaneWorkaround
{
    public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
    {
        bool isformdisplayed = false;
        WorkaroundForm workaroundForm;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        public MyUserControl()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Name = "MyUserControl";
            this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.MyUserControl_Paint);
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.MyUserControl_Resize);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

            this.Paint += MyUserControl_Paint;
            this.Resize += MyUserControl_Resize;
        }

        private void MyUserControl_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           this.Paint += MyUserControl_Paint;
        }

        private void MyUserControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isformdisplayed)
            {
                this.SuspendLayout();
                workaroundForm = new WorkaroundForm();
                SetParent(workaroundForm.Handle, this.Handle);
                workaroundForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                workaroundForm.Width = Width;
                workaroundForm.Height = Height;
                workaroundForm.Show();
                isformdisplayed = true;
                this.ResumeLayout();
            }
        }

        private void MyUserControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isformdisplayed)
            {
                workaroundForm.Width = this.Width;
                workaroundForm.Height = this.Height;
            }
        }
    }
}

//WorkaroundForm.cs

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TaskPaneWorkaround
{
    public partial class WorkaroundForm: Form
    {
        public WorkaroundForm()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(509, 602);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.WorkaroundForm_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
        private void WorkaroundForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
            webBrowser.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.ResumeLayout();
            webBrowser.Focus();
            webBrowser.Navigate(new System.Uri("https://bing.com"));
        }
    }
}
```